# How to pass method of arbitrary type into a procedure and identify it?

Tags: delphi

I have a thread library which has three constructors for three different method types. I want them to be merged into one and some kind of logic to tell them apart inside the constructor. Is it possible? As there is `TValue` for values and such, is there a similar thing for method types?

I have the following types supported for now;

```
TAgThreadMethod1 = procedure of object;
TAgThreadMethod2 = procedure;
TAgThreadMethod3 = procedure(const AThread: TAgThread) of object;
```

and the constructors are like so:

```
constructor Create(const AOnRun: TAgThreadMethod1); overload; virtual;
constructor Create(const AOnRun: TAgThreadMethod2); overload; virtual;
constructor Create(const AOnRun: TAgThreadMethod3); overload; virtual;
```

For reference, I don't want the user to have the ability to change the worker method at a later time after the construction at all. So if a solution exists which can do something like this in a single constructor, is also welcome;

```
constructor Create
            (const AOnRun: [Some type which can hold arbitrary method types]);
begin

  // code to identify the method contained in AOnRun.
  // if supported, assign it the correct handler.

end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't any good way to do this, because the whole point of a method pointer is to be invoked at some later point, and you can't do that unless you know its signature. So losing the distinction between signatures is very counterproductive.

If you only want to have to store one type of call inside your object, you could make the three constructors each create an anonymous method with a unified signature that wraps calls to the three types, and just store that instead of having to deal with multiple distinct method types.  But what you're asking for, specifically, won't work.

Comment: ok, i think i get what you are saying. Though, is there a way to identify the type of a method pointer through rtti maybe? I was trying to accommodate multiple types of methods so I don't have to make multiple constructors for those.

Comment: @Umair: No, there's no way to identify a method pointer through RTTI.  Internally, it's just a pointer.  You can do that trick on an object because each object has a hidden field that references its VMT, and the VMT has a pointer to the RTTI tables, but a method pointer doesn't have anything like that for you to make that determination at runtime.

Comment: @Umair: Also, I don't know exactly what it is you're trying to do, but when you say "thread library that takes multiple method pointer types," the first thing that comes to my mind is "I've seen something very similar before, in [OmniThreadLibrary](http://otl.17slon.com/)."  Have you looked at it?

Comment: I do have the source, I'll look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the best that you can do is have a constructor that accepts the most general form of the procedural type. That is `TProc<TAgThread>`. This will be the master constructor, the only virtual constructor. You can then delegate the other constructors to the master constructors.

To recap, the [declaration in `SysUtils`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TProc) is:

```
type
  TProc<T> = reference to procedure(Arg1: T);
```

So your master constructor is:

```
constructor Create(AOnRun: TProc<TAgThread>); overload; virtual;
```

The other constructors are not virtual and might look like this:

```
constructor Create(AOnRun: TAgThreadMethod1); overload;
```

Implemented as:

```
constructor TMyClass.Create(AOnRun: TAgThreadMethod1);
begin
  Create(
    procedure(Thread: TAgThread)
    begin
      AOnRun();
    end;
  );
end;
```

The master constructor, the virtual one, does all the work. The other constructors, the non-virtual ones, adapt their arguments to fit that of the master constructor.

Comment: The argument on `TProc<T>` is **not** const.

Comment: @Stefan I must be thinking of my own version which is const. One wonders what goes through the minds of the emba people.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but not with only a TValue.

Instead of passing the method itself, you could pass it as a TRttiMethod like this: `MyRegisterMethod(TRttiContext.GetType(TMyClassType).GetMethod('MyMethodName'));`
If you want to pass all constructors you will need to use a loop like this:

```
for MyMethod in TRttiContext.GetType(TMyClassType).GetMethods do
  if MyMethod.IsConstructor then // As in your example you only want constructors
    MyRegisterMethod(MyMethod);
```

Later, you can call this method like this: `MyRegisteredMethod.Invoke(nil, MyMethodParams)`. MyMethodParams is an array of TValue, which you will need to provide. This can be stored in a TValue itself (although it might be easier to just store them in a TArray). Note that you will only want to use `nil` in the invoke in case of a class method.

If you want to make sure the parameters are OK, you can verify them by looking them up in `MyRttiMethod.GetParameters` and compare their actual types to the actual types of the TValues in the array of TValue. This can also be used to find the correct method as well.

Comment: Your solution does address the issue when it comes to methods associated in classes but not those which are not. Thanks for the insight though.

Comment: @Umair that's true. as you declare the methods as a type, using Rtti might still be usable. I can't try this at the moment but it does intrigue me. Maybe I'll have done time to look into it later this week.